# How to move a image view down on swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have an image view and I needed the user swipe this image down but i don't know how to do this. I put a log to know if the swiping its working and its working well, i want that the image moves when I swipe. I'm very new in iOS. Can you help me??

Here is my ViewController class:

```
class MainScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var buttonMenuEntry: UIButton
    @IBOutlet var buttonMenuExit: UIButton
    @IBOutlet var mainscreenEntryView: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet var mainscreenCard: UIImageView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var swipeCardDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToGesture:")
        swipeCardDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        self.mainscreenCard.addGestureRecognizer(swipeCardDown)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonMenuClicked(sender: UIButton){

        buttonMenuEntry.hidden = true
        buttonMenuExit.hidden = false
    }

    func respondToGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
        println("Swiped down")

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried updating the frame of mainscreenEntryView with the swipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be:

```
func respondToGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, animations: {

            mainscreenCard.frame = CGRectMake(mainscreenCard.frame.origin.x,
                self.view.frame.height,
                mainscreenCard.frame.size.width,
                mainscreenCard.frame.size.height)
        })

}
```

Adjust your timing as you wish